# asterisk redirect calls is it possible

Tags: sip, asterisk

I have 2 sip phone numbers: sip1 and sip2. If someone calls me on sip1 and I am not online I would like to redirect the call on sip2. How to configure this in extensions.conf?

```
exten => sip1,1,Dial(SIP/sip1,20,tr)
exten => sip1,2,Voicemail()
exten => sip1,3,Hangup()
```

How to change the extensions.conf file in order to make the redirect call in case the client is not online. If the client is online and he doesn;t answer I want the call to go into voicemail. In case he is not online the call will be redirect to the second phone number.

Need some advice. Appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have samples in sample config file,why you not read that?

Here is how it have look like

```
[main]
exten => _sip1,1,Dial(SIP/sip1,20)                          ; Ring the interface, 20 seconds maximum
exten => _sip1,n,Goto(checkstatus-sip1,${DIALSTATUS},1)           ; Jump based on status (NOANSWER,BUSY,CHANUNAVAIL,CONGESTION,ANSWER)
[checkstatus-sip1]
exten => NOANSWER,1,Goto(main,sip2,1)        ; If unavailable, send to voicemail w/ unavail announce
exten => BUSY,1,Voicemail(${mbx},b)            ; If busy, send to voicemail w/ busy announce
exten => _.,1,Goto(BUSY,1);if other
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I would like to ask you do you know what are the reasons why in some cases the call from sip1 to sip2 failes? The error is: no response to our critical packets. I've debugged the message and the reasons why the call failes is the fact that the call-e phone doesn't respond to invite message ( a lot of re Nat...is going on..till the call failes).

Comment: "no response" mean somethign with network usualy. or other part ignore message. sorry, no way debug ur case remotly